# How do you access the .emacs file for customizations on an EC2 server?

Tags: emacs, amazon-ec2

How do you access the .emacs file for customizations on an EC2 server?  Do I have to create one myself?

The reason for doing so is that I'm getting annoyed with having to type M-x normal-erase-is-backspace-mode every time I open a file with emacs, so I'm trying to add the line 'normal-erase-is-backspace-mode 1' to the file.

Comment: ~/.emacs? If your sever gives you a home folder, surely you can put the .emacs there.

Comment: Am I supposed to create one, or should there already be one somewhere?

Comment: ok nevermind i just made one and put the line in there and it worked.  thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Emacs looks for the `.emacs` file in the home directory.](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html)  You can also save your init file as `/.emacs.el` or `~/.emacs.d/init.el` as well.